# dplyr & r: Anonymous functions myst be parenthesized

Tags: r, dplyr

I think I've stumbled apon my first error with a spelling mistake.

I am running the following code with R and dplyr.

```
> foobar = c(1,2,3)
> foobar %>% as.character
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

This works fine, now I try to run it through an anonymous function.

```
> foobar %>% function(x) x * 2 
Error: Anonymous functions myst be parenthesized
```

Any idea what is happening? (And where I need to ping to get 'myst' corrected to 'must')?

Comment: In `dplyr_0.4.0`, the error is `Error: Anonymous functions must be parenthesized`

Comment: The error message was fixed in the dev version of magrittr almost a month ago, so I imagine the fix will come to CRAN when magrittr 1.6 comes out. See here: https://github.com/smbache/magrittr/commit/e95aa63960e6926b701d0fe927587bacccb53f0f

Comment: I'm using dplyr 0.7.8 and still getting `Error: Anonymous functions myst be parenthesized`

Comment: Still myst with dplyr 1.0.0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error message is quite informative (even if one word is misspelled).  Put parentheses around the anonymous function.

```
foobar <- 1:3
foobar %>% (function(x) x * 2)
# [1] 2 4 6
```

For explanation, see the **Using %>% with call- or function-producing rhs** section in

```
help("%>%", "magrittr")
```

It has nothing to do with `dplyr`. As for the typo in the error message, whenever you find something that might need attention you can contact the package maintainer.  Although it seems [this has been fixed](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr/commit/e95aa63960e6926b701d0fe927587bacccb53f0f) in the most recent development version of `magrittr`.  An easy way to find the maintainer of a package is to use

```
maintainer("magrittr")
```

The result is omitted here because it contains an email address.