# use for loop with pipes in R

Tags: r, pipe

I am using pipes in R using magrittr library. I need to use for loop in between of the pipes, how would i do that

```
tmrank.ft <- regulartable(
data = tm.rank.out) %>% 
theme_booktabs() %>% 
autofit() %>%
merge_v(j=missing_species) %>%
align(align = 'center') %>%
align(align = 'center', part = 'header') %>% 
bold(part = 'header') %>%
height(height = 1, part = 'header') %>% 
fontsize(size = 14, part = 'all') %>% 
width(j=1, width = 1.0 ) %>%
width(j=2:ncol(tm.rank.out), width = 2.5) %>%
{
for (ii in 2:length(species))
{
  group_result <- group_vector(tm.rank.out.temp, grp.type, species[ii])
  for (jj in 1:length(group_result))
  {
    text_color <- grp.clr[[unique(grp.type[,grp][jj])]]
    color(i = group_result[[jj]], j = ~ species[ii], color = text_color)
  }
}
}
```

it throws me

> Error in inherits(x, "flextable") : 
>     argument "x" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piping requires functions whose first argument is `x`. So just pre-define the function with an argument `x`:

```
foo <- function(x){
  for (ii in 2:length(species))
{
  group_result <- group_vector(tm.rank.out.temp, grp.type, species[ii])
  for (jj in 1:length(group_result))
  {
    text_color <- grp.clr[[unique(grp.type[,grp][jj])]]
    color(i = group_result[[jj]], j = ~ species[ii], color = text_color)
  }
 }
}

tmrank.ft <- regulartable(
data = tm.rank.out) %>% 
theme_booktabs() %>% 
autofit() %>%
merge_v(j=missing_species) %>%
align(align = 'center') %>%
align(align = 'center', part = 'header') %>% 
bold(part = 'header') %>%
height(height = 1, part = 'header') %>% 
fontsize(size = 14, part = 'all') %>% 
width(j=1, width = 1.0 ) %>%
width(j=2:ncol(tm.rank.out), width = 2.5) %>%
foo()
```

Comment: the function must return "x". thats how I made it work.

Answer (score 2):

I hope the code can help you.

```
seq(1:10) %>% (function(x){
    print(x)
})
```

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074797/dplyr-r-anonymous-functions-myst-be-parenthesized) is talk about this method