# How can I pass dataframe variables to a for-loop using pipes with dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to iterate through some calculations on subsets of my df using a for-loop at the end of a dplyr pipe, but variables I pass to the for-loop from the df aren't recognized.

I've tried to follow steps from this post:
[use for loop with pipes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927265/use-for-loop-with-pipes-in-r).
Basically, I'm wrapping the for-loop in a user defined function and passing the df to the function via pipes.

I'm using a product sales dataset and am trying to calculate average sales of each pair of periods within each quarter for each product (a sort of sales baseline for promotions). For example, my first pass through the subset would calculate the average of periods 2 and 3, omitting 1. My second pass would exclude period 2 and calculate the average sales for 1 and 3, etc.

```
#Create dataframe
Article <- rep(1:3, each = 6)
Quarter <- rep(1:2, each = 3, 3)
Period <- rep(1:3, 6)
Sales <- sample(10:20, 18, replace = T)

df <-data.frame(Article, Quarter, Period, Sales)

foo <- function(x){
  for (i in unique(Period)) {
    filter(Period != i) %>%
      summarize(average_sales = mean(Sales))
  } 
  return(x)
}

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Article, Quarter) %>%
  foo() 

#Desired resultant df:
average_sales <- c(14.5, 16.5, 12, 12, 16, 15, 16.5, 12.5, 16, 15, 14, 18, 11.5, 11, 11.5, 16, 16, 12)
df$average_sales <- average_sales
print(df, row.names = F)
Article Quarter Period Sales average_sales
      1       1      1    14          14.5
      1       1      2    10          16.5
      1       1      3    19          12.0
      1       2      1    19          12.0
      1       2      2    11          16.0
      1       2      3    13          15.0
      2       1      1    12          16.5
      2       1      2    20          12.5
      2       1      3    13          16.0
      2       2      1    17          15.0
      2       2      2    19          14.0
      2       2      3    11          18.0
      3       1      1    11          11.5
      3       1      2    12          11.0
      3       1      3    11          11.5
      3       2      1    12          16.0
      3       2      2    12          16.0
      3       2      3    20          12.0
```

I know this code still doesn't give me my end result, which would ideally be a fifth variable in the df which contains, for each period, the mean sales of the other two periods, but this is where I'm stuck. I'm not even sure if a for-loop is the best/most efficient way to solve this problem (I'm a limited R coder and not familiar with the entire suite of tidyverse tools), but any suggestions on how to complete the dataframe would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the expected result as an example?

Comment: Your function takes one argument named `x`. It then does some unrelated stuff in a loop (`x` isn't used in the loop), never assigning anything (no `<-` or `=` inside the loop), so nothing that happens in the loop is saved, and then it returns `x`, the unmodified input. (The purpose of this comment is to try to help you understand why your function isn't working... I'm sure someone will be along with a nice solution soon.)

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for feedback. Novice coder here (as all intermediate coders identify themselves, lol). I was assuming that the df is passed as `x` via the pipes, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: The `df` is indeed passed as `x`, to the function. But then you don't use `x` inside the function at all, except to return it at the end. Inside your for loop, inside the function, you need to tell `filter` to use `x`, `x %>% filter...`. But you also need to save the results of each loop iteration somewhere. You run all the right calculations, but since you don't assign them with `<-` or `=`, they're not stored.

Comment: @LloydChristmas Done.

Comment: @akrun Not specifically. I was considering a `for` loop to solve this problem, but your solution is much more efficient. I'll mark it as the answer, but first I need to test it on my original code. My actual dataset is also by week (I kept it simple using just period in this example), so I need to modify your solution to fit my data.

Comment: @Gregor If I were to use `x %>% filter(...` within the `for` loop, would I also use `i in unique(x$Period)` as for the loop sequence?

Comment: Yes. `foo` doesn't know what `Period` is or where to look for it. The pipe itself doesn't do any magic on that---all that functionality is coded into the `dplyr` functions `mutate`, `filter`, `summarize`, etc. `x %>% foo %>% bar` is just a different way of writing `bar(foo(x))`. The pipe doesn't care if `x` is a data frame, a vector, or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer, with some simplified examples to try to help you understand how to fix your function:

```
foo1 <- function(x) {
  1 + 2
  return(x)
}

foo1(0)
# [1] 0
```

`foo1` is my simplified version of your function. In takes in an argument `x`, does something that doesn't use `x`, and then returns `x`. It's a pointless function - it doesn't matter that we do `1 + 2`, because nothing is done with the result. In its last line, `foo1` returns the same value that was passed to it, untouched.

```
foo2 <- function(x) {
  x + 1
  return(x)
}

foo2(0)
# [1] 0
```

`foo2` is a little bit better, but ultimately equally pointless. The calculation in the middle uses `x`, which is logically a step forward, but the result, `x + 1`, isn't saved, and the function still returns the original `x` that was passed in.

```
foo3 <- function(x) {
  y <- x + 1
  return(y)
}

foo3(0)
# [1] 1
```

Finally, a function that does something! `foo3` adds 1 to its input, modifies the input to store that result in a new variable `y`, (it could just as well modify `x`, `x <- x + 1`), and then it returns the modified variable.

With a `for` loop, you can't just do `y <- for(...)`, we need to do the assignment *inside* the loop:

```
foo4 <- function(x) {
  for(i in 1:3) {
    y <- x + i
  }
  return(y)
}

foo4(0)
# [1] 3
```

`foo4` shows a common beginner mistake - `y` is modified each time through the loop, but it is overwritten each time. `y` will be `x + 1`, the first time through, then `y` will be `x + 2`, then when `i` is 3 `y` will be `x + 3`, with no memory of the previous iterations. We need to give `y` some length, so it can store each iteration separately.

```
foo5 <- function(x) {
  y <- numeric(3)
  for(i in 1:3) {
    y[i] <- x + i
  }
  return(y)
}

foo5(0)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

`foo5` is good! We initialize `y` to have the right length, and each iteration of the loop saves its result to a different part of `y`, and then the whole `y` is returned at the end.

```
foo <- function(x) {
  y <- list() # with a `list`, we don't absolutely need to specify the length upfront
  for(i in unique(x$Period)) {
    # use [[ for list assignment
    y[[i]] <- x %>%
      filter(Period != i) %>%
      summarize(
        period_excluded = i, # we'll use this to keep track 
        average_sales = mean(Sales)
      )
  } 
  # do ourselves a favor and turn the list of data frames into a single data frame 
  # with bind_rows before returning
  return(bind_rows(y))
}

foo(df)
#   period_excluded average_sales
# 1               1      14.58333
# 2               2      14.16667
# 3               3      15.58333
```

Answer (score 1):

If we are looking for a way to get the `mean` of elements other than the 'Sales' for the particular 'period', get the difference of the 'Sales' with the `sum` of the 'Sales' for each 'Article', 'Quarter', and divide by length of the group -1.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Article, Quarter) %>%
   mutate(average_sales = (sum(Sales)- Sales)/(n()-1))
# A tibble: 18 x 5
# Groups:   Article, Quarter [6]
#   Article Quarter Period Sales average_sales
#     <int>   <int>  <int> <int>         <dbl>
# 1       1       1      1    14          14.5
# 2       1       1      2    10          16.5
# 3       1       1      3    19          12  
# 4       1       2      1    19          12  
# 5       1       2      2    11          16  
# 6       1       2      3    13          15  
# 7       2       1      1    12          16.5
# 8       2       1      2    20          12.5
# 9       2       1      3    13          16  
#10       2       2      1    17          15  
#11       2       2      2    19          14  
#12       2       2      3    11          18  
#13       3       1      1    11          11.5
#14       3       1      2    12          11  
#15       3       1      3    11          11.5
#16       3       2      1    12          16  
#17       3       2      2    12          16  
#18       3       2      3    20          12
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Article = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Quarter = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    Period = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Sales = c(14L, 10L, 19L, 19L, 11L, 
    13L, 12L, 20L, 13L, 17L, 19L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
    20L)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```