# How to loop a regression filtering for days

Tags: r

I try to loop a regression, and filter for only using the dates between -20 and -10 prior to the i.

Aspects:

1. need to be grouped by company
2. I want to run a regression for every date in the dataset -> thats why I have added for() loop
3. need to regress on date [-20,-10] with respect to the date in that row.
4. save intercept an beta in a new data frame (including date and company variable)

I run the following code:

```
stocks %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  for i:length(stocks$date){ 
    lm(Return~indexfactor, filter(stocks$date==c(i-20:i-10)))
    }
```

But get error that looks like this.. Is there someone better in R than me that could help me out here?

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  group_by(Company) %>%
  for i"
>     lm(Return~indexfactor, filter(stocks$date==c(i-50:i-10)))
Error in filter(stocks$date == c(i - 50:i - 10)) : object 'i' not found
>     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
```

head(stocks)

```
   Company      Return       date indexfactor
1:    TSLA          NA 2020-01-02           1
2:    TSLA  0.02963319 2020-01-03           2
3:    TSLA  0.01925467 2020-01-06           3
4:    TSLA  0.03880052 2020-01-07           1
5:    TSLA  0.04920485 2020-01-08           2
6:    TSLA -0.02194501 2020-01-09           3
```

dput:

```
library(dplyr)

structure(list(Company = c("TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", 
"TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", 
"TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", 
"TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", 
"TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
"MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT"), Return = structure(c(NA, 
-0.00231580860313196, 0.00161115249502686, 0.0263778178160983, 
0.00126177020327534, 0.00131321050919397, -0.0246270372908958, 
0.00914064109251655, 0.00200537012113067, 0.0152319401903576, 
0.00153470089029306, 0.00330255357802023, -0.0386048629818018, 
0.0126135313891698, 0.016987201324169, 0.00226083596494164, 0.0275330390995761, 
0.0219139834854407, -0.017438317910401, 0.00482277896193928, 
-0.00746184998902322, -0.000335287830383391, 0.00813970000264619, 
-0.00120277144206837, 0.00276710299297744, 0.0138741424465028, 
-0.0102317198037775, 0.00821145028213532, 0.0174002689158261, 
0.00665249242034749, 0.00892635726223312, 0.0301960379663551, 
0.0321221724831346, -0.00671175495130083, 0.0017702430543638, 
0.0325710468824816, NA, 0.00747491336551409, 0.004230452491915, 
0.0154892997636558, -0.0100836108228525, -0.00670488036422623, 
-0.0331018742668066, 0.0038934147553642, -0.00956207269350584, 
0.00614369450930652, -0.00161045428175832, -0.0183479745173454, 
-0.0213610573923191, 0.00342794874173857, 0.0168724333689398, 
0.00671920438590856, 0.00061292650530631, -0.0105499797243396, 
-0.0238012734333519, 0.00648296789562508, -0.00931178310842573, 
0.00812716607773845, -0.0246056442175525, 0.0141584160856578, 
0.00630712914529696, 0.00908445774647904, -0.00272174624225163, 
-0.000629783091523284, -0.00910302512573391, -0.00423991959013226, 
0.0202256115186827, 0.00751252808543867, 0.0118061795583038, 
0.0150801225162718, 0.00336111869323474, 0.00147394484369379, 
NA, -0.00225290073646667, -3.31363114687289e-05, -0.00318795893000134, 
9.9933375639738e-05, -0.00985973514785521, -0.0051808544995795, 
0.00432856189833641, 0.00942799115889392, 0.0167784043797137, 
0.0013122301384898, -0.0175283598141395, -0.0185747393633032, 
0.00169894672234916, 0.012822249504298, 0.00328223940876526, 
-0.000701001473501162, -0.0173041352803581, -0.0362036357526352, 
0.00169304112099122, -0.00732389788732402, 0.0254681919300281, 
-0.0207195464395805, 0.0199569965714916, 0.0150643262548715, 
0.00593640984287869, 0, -0.00210274711678327, -0.00458826751020991, 
0.0117112569702396, 0.0217340016991259, 0.00482243104872015, 
0.0101246444598198, 0.00305900606094878, -0.00266037365193483, 
0.0108975178309423), .Dim = c(108L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    "Delt.1.arithmetic")), date = structure(c(18871, 18872, 18873, 
18877, 18878, 18879, 18880, 18883, 18884, 18885, 18886, 18887, 
18890, 18891, 18892, 18893, 18894, 18897, 18898, 18899, 18900, 
18901, 18904, 18905, 18906, 18907, 18908, 18911, 18912, 18913, 
18914, 18915, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18921, 18871, 18872, 18873, 
18877, 18878, 18879, 18880, 18883, 18884, 18885, 18886, 18887, 
18890, 18891, 18892, 18893, 18894, 18897, 18898, 18899, 18900, 
18901, 18904, 18905, 18906, 18907, 18908, 18911, 18912, 18913, 
18914, 18915, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18921, 18871, 18872, 18873, 
18877, 18878, 18879, 18880, 18883, 18884, 18885, 18886, 18887, 
18890, 18891, 18892, 18893, 18894, 18897, 18898, 18899, 18900, 
18901, 18904, 18905, 18906, 18907, 18908, 18911, 18912, 18913, 
18914, 18915, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18921), class = "Date"), indexfactor = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c("2021-09-01", 
"2021-09-02", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-08", "2021-09-09", 
"2021-09-10", "2021-09-13", "2021-09-14", "2021-09-15", "2021-09-16", 
"2021-09-17", "2021-09-20", "2021-09-21", "2021-09-22", "2021-09-23", 
"2021-09-24", "2021-09-27", "2021-09-28", "2021-09-29", "2021-09-30", 
"2021-10-01", "2021-10-04", "2021-10-05", "2021-10-06", "2021-10-07", 
"2021-10-08", "2021-10-11", "2021-10-12", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-14", 
"2021-10-15", "2021-10-18", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-20", "2021-10-21", 
"2021-09-011", "2021-09-021", "2021-09-031", "2021-09-071", "2021-09-081", 
"2021-09-091", "2021-09-101", "2021-09-131", "2021-09-141", "2021-09-151", 
"2021-09-161", "2021-09-171", "2021-09-201", "2021-09-211", "2021-09-221", 
"2021-09-231", "2021-09-241", "2021-09-271", "2021-09-281", "2021-09-291", 
"2021-09-301", "2021-10-011", "2021-10-041", "2021-10-051", "2021-10-061", 
"2021-10-071", "2021-10-081", "2021-10-111", "2021-10-121", "2021-10-131", 
"2021-10-141", "2021-10-151", "2021-10-181", "2021-10-191", "2021-10-201", 
"2021-10-211", "2021-09-012", "2021-09-022", "2021-09-032", "2021-09-072", 
"2021-09-082", "2021-09-092", "2021-09-102", "2021-09-132", "2021-09-142", 
"2021-09-152", "2021-09-162", "2021-09-172", "2021-09-202", "2021-09-212", 
"2021-09-222", "2021-09-232", "2021-09-242", "2021-09-272", "2021-09-282", 
"2021-09-292", "2021-09-302", "2021-10-012", "2021-10-042", "2021-10-052", 
"2021-10-062", "2021-10-072", "2021-10-082", "2021-10-112", "2021-10-122", 
"2021-10-132", "2021-10-142", "2021-10-152", "2021-10-182", "2021-10-192", 
"2021-10-202", "2021-10-212"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Piping into a wrongly formatted for-loop will throw some errors. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927265/use-for-loop-with-pipes-in-r/53927437 - put the for-loop in a function and take it from there. Note, it is safer to use `for (i in seq_along(x)){your code here}`

Comment: @DonaldSeinen thank you! As Im quite new to R its a bit greek to me many of the examples in Stack. Could you give me an example of how you think the pipe should be structured (also using 'seq_along()' instead of 'length()')

Comment: can you use `dput(stocks)` and put it in the question and add any `library` calls that you use? Note - most likely don't need a for-loop here.

Comment: @DonaldSeinen is it correct now? I have only used the dplyr package, but please feel free to use any other package that you think can solve this.

Comment: eventually `filter(stocks$date %in% ((i-20):(i-10)) )`

Comment: @jogo so you mean:

`stocks %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  for i:length(stocks$date){ 
    lm(Return~indexfactor, filter(stocks$date %in% ((i-20):(i-10)) ))
    }`

am I right?

Comment: @thomas.diridondo Please compare `i <- 22; (i-20:i-10)` vs. `i <- 22; ((i-20):(i-10))`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69678838/all-regression-output-summed-up-in-single-cell-issue